# Hide sensitive post data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, passwords

Django has some [nice helpers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters) for ensuring sensitive data (passwords, credit card data) never gets reflected in logs or error output. This functionality is also available in some third-party tools like [Raygun](https://raygun.io/docs/languages/ruby)

**Is there a built-in equivalent for Laravel?**

For example, error pages and presumably debug emails include the complete raw POST data; I would like to strip this out.

One approach is to remove keys from `$_POST` after reading from it, but is this enough to prevent accidental password exposure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

If you're debugging something then it definitely makes sense for debug mode to show you what's going on and to not hide anything from you. With that said, no one would use debug mode in production so there really shouldn't be any fear of exposing sensitive data there. Unless you are explicitly logging this data or showing it to the user somewhere Laravel wouldn't do that in production mode.

Comment: No but you also don't want user passwords reflected in logs, for example.

Comment: If a password ends up in your logs it would be because you put it there. I don't see where Laravel would do this.